# How do I launch emacs in terminal mode within Powershell?

Tags: emacs, powershell

When I do the obvious thing in Powershell:

```
Start-Process "C:\bin\emacs-23.3\bin\emacs.exe" -ArgumentList "-nw"
```

Then emacs loads a new "cmd.exe" terminal, within which it is in terminal mode, instead of starting in terminal mode within Powershell. How can I start emacs in terminal mode within the existing Powershell terminal?

Comment: Actually it doesn't load in a new "cmd.exe" terminal. cmd.exe is not a terminal, it's a program. Emacs opens with its own console window instead of using powershell's. Don't believe me? Try looking for cmd.exe in your process list. It won't be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test it cause I don't use emacs. Does it load within PowerShell if you just invoke it?

```
C:\bin\emacs-23.3\bin\emacs.exe -nw
```

Comment: Doh, yes it does. I did that with "runemacs.exe", and that did not work, but I never did it with "emacs.exe". Stupid me...

Answer (score 1):

Install GNU Emacs from winget

```
winget install "GNU Emacs"
```

Then add this code block in your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

```
$emacs_wildcard = "${Env:ProgramFiles}\Emacs\*\bin\emacs.exe"
if ($(Test-Path $emacs_wildcard)) {
  $emacs_path = (Get-ChildItem $emacs_wildcard)[-1].FullName -replace ' ', '` '
  function emacs { "$emacs_path -nw $args" | Invoke-Expression }
}
```